# How to resolve Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.?

Tags: magento2.3.1

I am facing this issue Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.

some times and sometimes not.
1. When I add Product to cart.
2. When I want to delete a product from a cart. 
3. When I want to Update a cart.
4. When I want to Register.
5. When I load ajax Filter with own a javascript code.

So many times its comes localhost as well as on staging server.

So Please let me know how to resolve this issue permanently.

Staging Url is ==>https://magento-331546-1017597.cloudwaysapps.com

Comment: are you using Firefox?

Comment: no chrome, but its doesn't matter chrome or firefox or else. I hope It works for all. right.

Comment: When I add Product to cart. 2. When I want to delete a product from a cart these two opreations are fine in my side

Comment: yes, some time works and some times not. and the issue is in chrome mostly.

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/25427 i added an issue on github , Hope get a Solution soon

Comment: so is there a solution is available or people will add solutions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/100575/discussion-between-sarvesh-dineshkumar-patel-and-waqar-ali).

Comment: tema magento will give a solution soon